# Getting github link for code release

Tags: git, github, wget, release

Long story short, I am developing a script which relies on the user downloading a tar.gz from a link provided by me. I am also not allowed to download the tar.gz myself.

The tar.gz is actually a specific release of a github repo. The link is 
https://github.com/ros/urdfdom_headers/archive/1.0.0.tar.gz .
The problem is that if you open this link in a browser, the downloaded file will be named `urdfdom_headers-1.0.0.tar.gz`, exactly as I want. However, if the user decided to directly download using wget, the name of the file will be `1.0.0.tar.gz`. My script relies on the name of the archive and although I can account for the differences in the names, having a consistent name will ease up my life substantially.

My question is whether there is a github link to that project that stores the archive with the name `urdfdom_headers-1.0.0.tar.gz` rather than `1.0.0.tar.gz`, so that any type of download will result in safe naming. The link for the releases is https://github.com/ros/urdfdom_headers/releases/

Answer (score 0):

> My question is whether there is a github link to that project that stores the archive with the name urdfdom_headers-1.0.0.tar.gz rather than 1.0.0.tar.gz

In the case where there is no such link, your script is just one command away to work (in a bash session):

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -regex '^./[0-9].*\.tar\.gz' -exec echo '{}' \; | sed -e "s/^\.\///g" | while read f; do mv "${f}" "urdfdom_headers-${f}"; done
```

In multiple lines for visibility:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -regex '^./[0-9].*\.tar\.gz' -exec echo '{}' \; | \
  sed -e "s/^\.\///g" | \
  while read f; do mv "${f}" "urdfdom_headers-${f}"; done
```

So if there are any downloaded `tar.gz` files starting with a number, they will be renamed accordingly.

Comment: I am not asking how to find and rename the file. I want to know whether there is such link on github so I can download the file with a proper name directly. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @niko My point is: I don't think there is such a link, hence my workaround.